# Unexpected working of printf() in C

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=2;
    printf("%d %d \n",++i,++i);
}
```

The above code gives an output `4 4`. Can any one help how to explain the output?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. See for example here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694756/how-pre-and-postfix-are-evaluated-in-printf

Answer (score 2):

++i is a prefix increment. Printf should first evaluate its arguments before printing them (although in which order, is not guaranteed and, strictly speaking, undefined - See Wiki entry on Undefined Behavior: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior ).

The prefix increment is called "increment and fetch", i.e. it first increments the value and then gives it to the caller.

In your case, `i` was first incremented twice, and only afterwards the output was formatted and sent to the console.

Comment: How did this answer get a vote? `in func(a,a++) , is not comma operator, its merely a separator between the arguments a and a++. The behaviour is undefined in that case if a is considered to be a primitive type) `

Comment: @Acme I voted it up, it doesn't mention the comma operator at all? But it does mention the fact that this is simply a function call, and that calls need to evaluate all their arguments before doing the actual call, which seems to the the point that is confusing the OP.

Comment: @unwind - There is a subtle difference in what you are saying and in the answer. The answer is talking about order of evaluation being unspecified which is correct, but it does not mention it to be UB . This `In your case, i was first incremented twice, and only afterwards the output was formatted and sent to the console.` is not correct. This `printf("%d %d \n",++i,++i);` is clear cut UB. What will be evaluated first this `"%d %d \n"`, this `++i` or this `++i` - think about it.

Comment: @Acme what is not correct? Do you meant that printf could start formatting before evaluating what's getting into the formatted string?

Comment: Reasoning out Undefined Behavior.@Ashalynd

Comment: @Acme: that's true, I should have been more critical. Can't undo my +1 now, though. :|

Comment: @Acme it is indeed UB. I should have mentioned that term I guess.

Comment: @unwind - Both the answers have made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with sequence points and it can result in undefined behavior.

Straight from Wikipedia:

> Before a function is entered in a function call. The order in which
>   the arguments are evaluated is not specified, but this sequence point
>   means that all of their side effects are complete before the function
>   is entered.

More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers have made the same mistake. Its clear cut UB and not just unspecified behavior.

What you have experienced is [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Please read about sequence points. Comma is a separator in function calls not an operator.

A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete. The sequence points listed in the C standard are:

> at the end of the evaluation of a full expression (a full
>   expression is an expression statement, or any other expression which
>   is not a subexpression within any larger expression);
>       at the ||, &&, ?:, and comma operators; and
>       at a function call (after the evaluation of all the arguments, and just before the actual call).

The Standard states that

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

What will be evaluated first this `"%d %d \n"`, this `++i` or this `++i` (second one) - think about it. This would be unspecified behavior:

```
void f(int x)
{
    printf("%d ",x);
}
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    f(i++) ;
}
```

From wiki:

> Before a function is entered in a function call.  The order in which
>   the arguments are evaluated is not specified, but this sequence point
>   means that all of their side effects are complete before the function
>   is entered.  In the expression f(i++) + g(j++) + h(k++), f is called
>   with a parameter of the original value of i, but i is incremented
>   before entering the body of f. Similarly, j and k are updated before
>   entering g and h respectively.  However, it is not specified in which
>   order f(), g(), h() are executed, nor in which order i, j, k are
>   incremented. Variables j and k in the body of f may or may not have
>   been already incremented. Note that a function call f(a,b,c) is not a
>   use of the comma operator and the order of evaluation for a, b, and c
>   is unspecified.